# E926: Current location list was changed error when pressing Enter in quickfix

Tags: quickfix

I have a quickfix window that lists errors in my php file like

```
tests/phpunit/MyTest.php|425 error| unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)
```

I used to be able to hit Enter and jump to the file and line, but now I just get an error:

```
E926: Current location list was changed
```

I'm on neovim 0.5.0.

Comment: `:h E926` says _If the current quickfix or location list was changed by an |autocommand| while processing a quickfix or location list command, it will be aborted._ Does this help you diagnose the problem?

Comment: right. Well maybe. I use CoC and I think that may be creating the quickfix results so I'll go bark up that tree and report back! Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the Syntastic plugin, which has not been updated since 2019.

I think it might be https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues/1127

Comment: I'm impressed with how polite you were towards that dude who posted a pretty snotty reply. ;)